# GPU stopped working after reinstalling windows

Tags: windows-10, drivers, amd-radeon, adobe-after-effects

I recently reinstalled Windows 10 and my AMD Radeon HD 7400M stopped working. After reinstalling Windows there was a notification telling me to change the video settings from AMD Catalyst Control settings. My GPU drivers were the latest one.

When I ran Adobe After Effects CC for the first time, it said that a GPU was detected but said it couldn't be used. Why did this happen and what can I do to fix it? My laptop has an i5-2450m and a 4GB of RAM.

Comment: provide us some of the more important information from your dxdiag report specifically driver version information.

Comment: This question really could use some clarification, but since OP hasn't been seen on the site since Jan 29 I suspect we won't be getting any. Anyway, if as stated *the GPU stopped working* then the OP would be seeing nothing on the screen. Given as that is unlikely, a more detailed description of the problem would likely be called for.